# Determine if a property is an auto property

Tags: c#, roslyn, analyzer

I'm trying to figure out if a property is an auto property i.e.
`public int Foo { get; set; }`

Stared for a while at `PropertyDeclarationSyntax` and `IPropertySymbol` but did not find anything.

Guess an alternative is an extension method that evaluates if `get` & `set` does not contain any statements is one way but it does not feel very elegant.

Comment: Well technically speaking, there are no auto-properties. It's syntactic sugar that the compiler turns into an implicit field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check whether any of the `AccessorDeclarationSyntax`es in the `PropertyDeclarationSyntax`'s `AccessorList` have a non-null `Body`.

You can see this by looking at any property declaration using the Syntax Visualizer (from the Roslyn SDK extension).

Comment: There's a new property: `ExpressionBody`. If it's assigned, `Body` is null, but the property is not an "auto-property".

Answer (score 2):

This [blog](https://jaylee.org/archive/2020/07/19/how-to-get-the-syntaxnode-for-a-symbol-using-roslyn.html) gives a good explanation:

In summary,

```
var isExplicitProperty = node
    .DescendantNodesAndSelf()
    .OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>()
    .Any(prop =>
    {
        if(prop.AccessorList != null)
        {
            return prop.AccessorList.Accessors
                .Any(a => a.Body != null || a.ExpressionBody != null);
        }

        // readonly arrow property declaration
        return true;
    });
```

Based on the internal [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/ba014d9d7728de0d4b5df3859507f9701e7032c0/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Symbols/Source/SourcePropertySymbol.cs#L205)

Comment: why not just `bool isAutoProperty = property.ExpressionBody == null && (property.AccessorList == null || property.AccessorList.Accessors.All(a => a.Body == null && a.ExpressionBody == null));`?
I used it just now and seems fine